# How do you find the entry point(s) in an Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse

You download an Eclipse project from GitHub and click Run: 
**"The Selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."**
What's the trick for finding entry point(s)?

Comment: First you need to know what sort of project it is. An Eclipse Plugin, for example, doesn't have an entry point.

Comment: @greg-449 it's an app. You're right, I did have to pick the type of project from the Run As configuration, then it showed me all the possible entry points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click your project, there should be a dropdown menu containing 'Run configuration' somewhere. From here, you should be able to set which class has its main method run when you click Run.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks much.

Comment: No problem, if it works then feel free to accept the answer.